# plotting box plot with seaborn with multidimensional data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to create a box plot with seaboard as follows:

I have some synthetic data where I have 24 different categories which are generated as:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10, 130, step=5)
```

Now, for each of these categories I generate 5 random observations as follows:

```
y = np.zeros(shape=(len(y), 5)) # Each row contains 5 observations for a category
```

Now, what I want to do is do a box plot with seaboard where I plot these 5 values along the y-axes (highlighting the confidence interval) and on the x-axes, I would like each of these categories. So, I do:

```
import seaborn as sis
fig = sns.boxplot(x=x, y=y)
fig.plt.show()
```

However, this comes with the exception that the data must be 1-dimensional. I am not sure how to structure my data so that I can plot it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as you point out, is the shape of your input data. Without trying to make too many assumptions as to what you are trying to do, I think you are looking for something like

```
x = np.arange(10, 130, step=5)
y = 4 * np.random.randn(x.size, 5) + 3

x_for_boxplot = np.repeat(x, 5)
y_for_boxplot = y.flatten()

ax = sns.boxplot(x_for_boxplot, y_for_boxplot)
```

where `x_for_boxplot` and `y_for_boxplot` have been restructured so that they are 1D arrays of the same size which is what `sns.boxplot` is looking for. I also changed `y` so that it is made up of random normal values rather than zeros.

[image]